# Angular: unit test varibles in subscribe

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, subscribe

I have a function that is setting a couple of values in subscribe:

```js
private getAllStatuses(): void {
   this.refControllerService.getAllStatus().subscribe(data => {
      this.StatusDTOList = data;
      this.canEditDate = this.isEditableStatus();
      this.isDEDUser = this.userAuthorisationService.isDEDUser();
      this.initialised = true;
   });
}
```

`canEditDate` & `isDEDUser` are both private, they are accessed in another function:

```js
public canEdit(): boolean {
   return this.isDEDUser && this.canEditDate;
}
```

I'm trying to set these two values in my test, but not having any look so far:

```js
it('StatusComponent canEdit should return false', () => {
    spyOn(refControllerService, 'getAllStatus').and.returnValue(of({ canEditDate: false, isDEDUser: false }) as any)
    spyOn(userAuthorisationServiceSpy, 'isDEDUser').and.returnValue(false)
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.canEdit).toBeFalsy();
});
```

I've tried a few different approaches, and I've searched for similar questions, I'm relatively new to angular, could someone explain is what I'm attempting possible? Can I set the values within that subscribe in a test, so that I can flip the values on and off for `canEdit()`?

Comment: When are you calling `canEdit`? Is it `this.isEditableStatus()`?

Comment: CanEdit is public and is the function under test, it can be called whenever...

Comment: What is this.isEditableStatus() doing? Are you sure it's not throwing any error, since it is not mocked?

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a lot of unclear things in the question. I would be brave to try answering it.

Considering `CanEdit is public and is the function under test` we need to execute the function to test it's result. Changing `expect(component.canEdit)` to `expect(component.canEdit())`.

we do not see how is the `getAllStatuses` executed. I would use it is called inside the `ngOnInit`. This function does some execution in an asynchronous way using the subscription to an Observable. That means we need to wait for that execution. Usually (not always though) `await fixture.whenStable()` is enough to wait for the execution of the async stuff. I suppose this test would archive the desired results:

```js
it('StatusComponent canEdit should return false', async () => {
    spyOn(refControllerService, 'getAllStatus').and.returnValue(of({ canEditDate: false, isDEDUser: false }) as any)
    spyOn(userAuthorisationServiceSpy, 'isDEDUser').and.returnValue(false)

    component.ngOnInit();
    await fixture.whenStable();

    expect(component.canEdit()).toBeFalsy();
});
```